# Compressed jQuery File Causing Content Security Policy Error in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, python-3.x, django-compressor

I have a hosted jquery file that I'm compressing using django compressor and serving via cloudflare.  Compression looks like this:

```
{% compress js %}
     <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.1.1.js' %}"> 
    </script>
 {% endcompress %}
```

I'm getting an error in Chrome console tools that says this:

`jquery.js:39 Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src https:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-bksOHsIG1boMjydqSfvQ5M7P7lTKHlinbm+hRfOd128='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.`

after searching around here i see that you can add some meta tags when loading an external js source...but how about in this case of a compressed file?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your hash has been provided in your error message.  And I'm guessing you can add it with the `integrity` attribute.  So the result/output of your actions should resemble this `<script>` tag:

```
<script 
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-bksOHsIG1boMjydqSfvQ5M7P7lTKHlinbm+hRfOd128="></script>
```

Comment: so, i tried that, not working.  everytime i reload it shows a new hash?  also tried with crossorigin="anonymous" but getting same exact error

Comment: What is the resulting html `<script>` tag? I understand that it can't fetch the JS file, but please list the resulting HTML. That might give us a clue.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.1.1.js' %}" 
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous">`

Comment: hey marc--was that what you were looking for?

Comment: Ok thanks for letting me know!  Tempted to just go back to the CDN at this point